# Computing weight of Galois represenetations

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-representations

I am a very beginner of the theory of weights. I am wondering whether there is an algorithm for computing the weights of given Galois representations. After I saw the notion of weight of Galois representations, I have tried to compute the weight of the $p$-adic Tate module $T_pE\otimes\mathbb{Q}_p$ of an ellitpic curve $E$ over a number field $F$. But, I immediately found that I even could not find a starting point of the computation. I presume that the case of $T_pE\otimes\mathbb{Q}_p$ would be a well-known example. If then, where can I find it? Moreover, as stated in the above, I am wondering whether there is a general framework for the computation.